# Not saving Certificate while recording in bin directory

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

When I start recording script it shows A certificate will be saved in bin. In bin a Certificate and .usr file were saved.
But then I delete the .crt and .usr file from the folder due to some reason.
Now again when I am doing the recording , it shows the message that the certificate will be saved in bin but when check it shows no certificate saved over there.
Tried this many times.
And I permanently delete the files other I could recover them.

To test repeatability, the .crt and .usr were removed and the test was
repeated. Upon start of the 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder', NO new .crt or .usr
file was created.

Answer (score 0):

Because these are only browser certificates, if you want JMeter to regenerate them you need to delete **proxyserver.jks** file, once you remove it - JMeter will re-generate it back along with *ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt* file and friends.

Alternatively you can get the files back using [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) or [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)

Also be aware that you can also record JMeter tests using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you don't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

And last but not the least, [as per JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading as your JMeter 3.2 is a little bit outdated